# std::default_random_engine generates the same values even with changing seed?

Tags: c++, random, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to implement a class that will serve as sort of a wrapper for the random library so I can use its objects and functions in (I think) a more intuitive way elsewhere in my code.

In my header I have something like this:

```
class RandomDevice{
private:
    unsigned long rand_seed;
    default_random_engine engine;
public:
    RandomDevice(unsigned long n);
    int randInt(int min, int max);};
```

And then in the .cpp file I implement those two functions (constructor and `randInt`) like so:

```
RandomDevice::RandomDevice(unsigned long n){
    rand_seed = n;
    default_random_engine engine;
    engine.seed(n);
}

int RandomDevice::randInt(int min, int max){
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);
    return distribution(engine);
}
```

Finally, in my `main.cpp` I test these functions like this:

```
int main(){
    unsigned long seed = 1;
    RandomDevice my_rand(seed);

    cout << "random integer: " << my_rand.randInt(0, 10) << endl;
}
```

The problem is, no matter what I set the seed to in `main.cpp`, I always get the same values for my random numbers (not just `randInt`, I have other distributions as well). I've also tried setting seed to `time(NULL)` but the same problem occurs.

I'm really scratching my head at this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
default_random_engine engine;
engine.seed(n);
```

This is seeding the local `engine`, which is destroyed at the end of the constructor, not the class member `engine`, which ends up being default constructed.

Use the member initializer list instead:

```
RandomDevice::RandomDevice(unsigned long n) : rand_seed(n), engine(n){ }
```

Comment: Yep, that did it!

`default_random_engine new_engine;`
`engine = new_engine;`
`engine.seed(n);`

worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @InvisibleAndre That's unnecessarily inefficient. See my edit.

Comment: This is the best answer.  There is no need to seed every time as proposed elsewhere.  The engine is designed to be seeded once, just don't throw the engine away.

Answer (score 15):

Try using std::chrono to feed the seed in each iteration or in every call. I think seeding time moments would give best randomness, since each time moment is a unique seed without any repetitions. I would do the following:

```
#include <chrono> 
...
default_random_engine engine; // or any other engine
engine.seed(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
```

Answer (score 1):

In your construction function, the new **created local** `engine` masks your **private class memeber** `engine` .
Just delete 2nd line of your `RandomDevice::RandomDevice()`, you will be fine.

Like this.

```
RandomDevice::RandomDevice(unsigned long n){
    rand_seed = n;
    engine.seed(n);
}
```

or using member intialize list as @T.C. said,

```
RandomDevice::RandomDevice(unsigned long n): rand_seed(n), engine(n) { }
```